# Why some PR curves aren't strictly decreasing

Tags: statistical-significance, model-evaluation

Since precision and recall are trade-off to each other. It seems to me all PR curves should be strictly decreasing (assuming (0,0) at bottom left). However, sometimes I do see PR curves (like following fig) that are not decreasing. Why would that be possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any randomness in the learning? Or is it fully deterministic?

Comment: It's an evaluation of a ML model (once trained, fully deterministic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example can illustrate what is happening.

Let's have data 1,...10. Let them have labels 'good' for odd and 'bad' for even.

The classifier in this example is to label first n numbers as good. If n is ten, recall is one. If n is zero, recall is zero.

The precision will oscillate up and down. For n one, it will be one. For n two, one half. For n three, two thirds. Later, your oscillation will be much less, but will remain.

Your data is more complex, but something similar may be happening there. The little peaks may mean: when increasing the number of positive predictions and growing recall, you luckily add more positive than negative examples.

Comment: Simple and clear example. Thank you. Still have a question though. Why is it usually happen (i.e., precision increase) when recall is low?